# how to toggle between the items in comboBox using c# .net for wpf application

Tags: c#

how to toggle between the items in comboBox using c# .net for wpf application.once i focus on combo box i can able to toggle between the items instead of focusing the comboBox i want to toggle between the items.

Comment: So what you want is to toggle the items if you for example click on the combobox, right ?

Comment: no albert.without clicking the combobox i want to toggle between items.i need shortcut for directly access the combobox items

Comment: But how you wanna do it. Which action is needed that you toggle between items. And do you have only 2 items or more ?

Comment: I have only two items.actually during that toggle it will change between two textboxes

Answer (score 0):

So maybe this is what you want, also I don't really know what you want.
This could help you.
If you have focus on the combobox you can toggle between both items by pressing key up or key down.

```
 public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        comboBox1.Items.Add("1");
        comboBox1.Items.Add("2");
        comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        comboBox1.Focus();
    }

    private void comboBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Up)
        {
            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex != 0)
                comboBox1.SelectedIndex--;
        }
        if (e.Key == Key.Down)
        {
            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex != comboBox1.Items.Count-1)
                comboBox1.SelectedIndex++;
        }

    }
}
```

**Ok then let's do it this way. The first event is called if the textbox text changes.
You should have something like that if I understood you correctly. The second one is the one you need.**

```
   private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //deleting all items
        comboBox1.Items.Clear();
        //adding text of each textbox if not empty
        if (textBox1.Text != "")
            comboBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text);
        if (textBox2.Text != "")
            comboBox1.Items.Add(textBox2.Text);
        //if combobox not empty select first item
        if (comboBox1.Items.Count != 0)
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
```

So what I did is. when one of the textboxes is selected and the user presses up or down then it toggles the content of the combobox. this event has to be assigned to each textbox as PreviewKeyDown event.

```
        private void textBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        //key up or key down
        if (e.Key == Key.Up || e.Key == Key.Down)
        {
            //has 2 items
            if (comboBox1.Items.Count == 2)
            {
                if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
                    comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 1;
                else
                    comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here the xaml code for the textboxes with the bound events.

```
    <TextBox Height="23" Margin="12,0,0,76" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="120" TextChanged="textBox_TextChanged" PreviewKeyDown="textBox_KeyDown" />
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,12,76" Name="textBox2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="120" TextChanged="textBox_TextChanged" PreviewKeyDown="textBox_KeyDown" />
```

Something I forgot to mention. It only works if one of the textboxes is focused. If you have further Items that can be focused then you have to add this event for every item to be sure that it is called no matter which of those items is focuesd right now.
Another possibility would be to create a keyboard hooker. But this is complicated.

Comment: Thanks you albert.But i want to toggle the items without focusing the combo box.

Comment: Ok maybe this time. Check the code starting at the bold text.